# tel: links from UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, tel

I opened tel: links in UIWebView through the following two methods。

1、

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function call(){
        window.location.href="tel://10086"
     }
</script>
<button type="button" onClick="call()">call 10086</button>
```

2、

```
<a href="tel://10086">href 10086</a>
```

When I do not implement any UIWebView Delegate Methods, both methods work well. But when  implement shouldStartLoadWithRequest and return YES, such as：

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    return YES;
}
```

the first method does not work, and error:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The URL can’t be shown" UserInfo=0x15b4f0    
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=tel://10086, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=tel://10086, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The URL can’t be shown}
```

the second well. Why?